# C Socket: error: expected ')' before '&' token in inet_aton();

Tags: c, sockets, websocket

I have currently a socket source. But somethings are wrong to the terminal. When I wrote gcc http_client.c or make http_client I got this error:

```
http_client.c: In function ‘main’:
http_client.c:24:25: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
int inet_aton(address, &remote_address.sin_addr.s_addr);
```

and

```
In file included from http_client.c:9:0:
/usr/include/arpa/inet.h:73:12: note: expected ‘struct in_addr *’ but
argument is of type ‘in_addr_t * {aka unsigned int *}’
extern int inet_aton (const char *__cp, struct in_addr *__inp) __THROW;
```

But there are made http_client and terminal saying me 'segmentation fault (core dumped)'  I have tried many ways, just nothing. How do I fix this errors?

Edit: When I wrote ./http_client 216.239.38.120 there are some commands:

```
Response from the server: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://www.google.com.tr/gfe_rd=cr&ei=z2WOV_WcHJTY8AeB85y4Cg
Content-Length: 262
Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 17:39:27 GMT

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A     HREF="http://www.google.com.tr/gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=z2WOV_WcHJTY8AeB85y4Cg">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

My http_client resources

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // for open
#include <unistd.h> // for close
#include <resolv.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *address;
address = argv[1];

int client_socket;
client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

// connect to an address
struct sockaddr_in remote_address;
remote_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
remote_address.sin_port = htons(80);
inet_aton(address, &remote_address.sin_addr.s_addr);

connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &remote_address, sizeof(remote_address));

char request[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
char response[4096];

send(client_socket, request, sizeof(request), 0);
recv(client_socket, &response, sizeof(response), 0);

printf("Response from the server: %s\n", response);
close(client_socket);

return 0;
}
```

Forgive me for my wrong language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
inet_aton(address, &remote_address.sin_addr.s_addr);
```

To

```
inet_aton(address, &remote_address.sin_addr);
```

Only seg fault I got was when I ran the application without giving a parameter.

ETA - check out the function prototype for inet_aton(), it accepts a ppointer to the sockaddr_in as opposed to an individual member of the structure.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
int inet_aton(const char *cp, struct in_addr *addr);
```

https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/inet_aton.3.asp

Comment: I am beginner for socket programming i C. So, this addr, and sin commands make me confused any times. And I did not try that. Thank you, it worked for me.

Comment: We all have to start somewhere, glad I could help.

Comment: I'm sorry for that but, make command worked successfully. ./http_client 216.239.38.120 is working. But I doubt it, because when I ran this command terminal have to give me the expires, cache-control, server, x-xss, x-frame,  and like that commands I think. Am I wrong? Simple info; this client work with my http_server.c source? In this source there is a char http_header[2048] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\n"; and terminal displaying Response from the server: HTTP/1.1 302 Found. I'm so so so confused

Comment: Sorry, i don't have enough information available to tell you much as you only posted the client code.

You should start a new question as this is a different problem and more information is required.